# Bash Shell syntax error done < $vid'

Tags: linux, bash, shell, syntax

i have a error

```
test: line 16: syntax error near unexpected token `done'
test: line 16: `               done < $vid'
```

my code test

```
read -p "entrer Liens Video ou le nom d'un fichier contenant des liens:" vid
            #Download Video
          if [[ -e $vid ]] ; then
             while read line
             do
                python vid-xml-decoder/ultimate.py $line
                find . -name "*.flv" | while read line
             do
                name="$(basename "${line}" .flv)"
                #Variable de déplacement de fichier
                repExport="./export/"
                #mux des fichier
                ffmpeg -i "${name}.flv" -vcodec copy -acodec copy mkvtemp.mkv
                mkvmerge -v -o "${repExport}${name}.mkv" --default-track 0 --language 0:fre "${name}.ass" mkvtemp.mkv && \

               done < $vid
                else
                  python vid-xml-decoder/ultimate.py $vid
                   # rest of video processing steps
                   find . -name "*.flv" | while read line
             do
                name="$(basename "${line}" .flv)"
                #Variable de déplacement de fichier
                repExport="./export/"
                #mux des fichier
                ffmpeg -i "${name}.flv" -vcodec copy -acodec copy mkvtemp.mkv
                mkvmerge -v -o "${repExport}${name}.mkv" --default-track 0 --language 0:fre "${name}.ass" mkvtemp.mkv && \
fi
```

in my script I want to offer two possible entering the links manually or with the text file in the same code

exemple

```
www.website.me/348744jnm
www.website.me/43545ljkjjk
www.website.me/554erer5cf
```

I have 3 links in my text file and the script will download then mux switch to another mux download links etc

Note: The script must accept space and special character

if you want more information please do not hesitate :)

tx for your help

Comment: At the very least use reasonable indentation. It would help you find at least some of the syntax problems you currently have... like the fact that you don't properly end the `while` in the `else` block or that you have continuation slashes on lines that don't need them (and are possibly swallowing lines you are intending to be parsed on their own.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error source:

```
            mkvmerge -v -o ..... nguage 0:fre "${name}.ass" mkvtemp.mkv && \
            # HERE ------------------------------------------------->      ^^
            # probably missing one line before "done"
            done < $vid
```

Comments:

- easier to debug and maintenace if you start using functions. Break your code to more maintenable parts... You can do anything with functinos as with external commands, like: `funcname | while read` .. or redirect its output like `funcname > somehere` and so on..
- double quote variables